# AddEventListener me muestra el resultado por 1 milisegundo

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una funcion con addEventListener, que cuando aprieto un boton me cambia el texto de un

, pero en el momento que hago click , me muestra el texto que cambia por 1 milisegundo y vuelve a su estado actual, por que sera?

Aca pongo el codigo a continuacion

```js
let $botonCalcular = document.getElementById("botonCalcular");
$botonCalcular.addEventListener("click",ClickenCalcular);
function ClickenCalcular(){
    let $nombreUsuario= document.querySelector('#nombre-usuario').value;
    let $edadUsuario= document.querySelector("#edad-usuario").value;
    let edadAutorizada = 18;
    let textoResultado;    
    
    if ($edadUsuario => edadAutorizada)
    {
       
        textoResultado= "Hola "+$nombreUsuario +" puedes ingresar"
    }
    else
    {
        textoResultado= "Hola "+$nombreUsuario +" no puedes ingresar"

    }
    document.querySelector("#resultado1").innerText=textoResultado;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=GFS+Didot">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bienvenida.css">
    <title>Entrada bar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div id="header">
            <header>
                <h1>Login bar</h1>
            </header>
        </div>
        <form id="formulario">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresá tu nombre" id="nombre-usuario"/>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresá tu nombre" id="edad-usuario"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Ingresar" id="botonCalcular" class="button"/>
        </form>
        <div id="resultado">
            <p id="resultado1">Resultado</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <footer>Proyecto para /r argentina</footer>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bienvenida.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pequeña observación: en `if ($edadUsuario => edadAutorizada)` el operador está invertido, debe ser `>=` (a no ser que estés pretendiendo usar una [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions))

Answer (score 2):

Si vas a utilizar el `form` para realizar las peticiones, entonces utiliza `event.preventDefault()` porque al tener un `input` con `type="submit"` este intentara enviar el formulario al servidor y como no especificastes nada en el `form`, te redireccionara a nada (blanco).

Si no vas a utilizar el `form` entonces simplemente modifica tu `input` por `type="button"`, con esto ya no sera necesario agregar el metodo anterior que dije y funcionara de la forma que quieres

En este caso estoy utilizando el metodo:

```js
let $botonCalcular = document.getElementById("botonCalcular");
$botonCalcular.addEventListener("click", ClickenCalcular);

function ClickenCalcular() {
  event.preventDefault(); //Esta linea nomas se agrega
  let $nombreUsuario = document.querySelector('#nombre-usuario').value;
  let $edadUsuario = document.querySelector("#edad-usuario").value;
  let edadAutorizada = 18;
  let textoResultado;

  if ($edadUsuario => edadAutorizada) {

    textoResultado = "Hola " + $nombreUsuario + " puedes ingresar"
  } else {
    textoResultado = "Hola " + $nombreUsuario + " no puedes ingresar"

  }
  document.querySelector("#resultado1").innerText = textoResultado;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=GFS+Didot">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bienvenida.css">
  <title>Entrada bar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div id="header">
      <header>
        <h1>Login bar</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
    <form id="formulario">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresá tu nombre" id="nombre-usuario" />
      <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresá tu nombre" id="edad-usuario" />
      <input type="submit" value="Ingresar" id="botonCalcular" class="button" />
    </form>
    <div id="resultado">
      <p id="resultado1">Resultado</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <footer>Proyecto para /r argentina</footer>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="bienvenida.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Pero ¿Que hace el `event.preventDefault()`?. Este metodo **cancela** el evento por defecto del `submit`(Que es enviar los datos al servidor) por eso ya no ocurre este suceso y se mantiene el proceso

**Referencias**

- [input-type-submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit)
- [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Otra opción válida también es cambiar el type de submit a button, de esta manera no ejecuta ese submit por defecto del formulario.

Comment: @jorgeGomez correcto pero como veo que lo puso dentro de un form, supongo que lo utilizara mas adelante para hacer peticiones aunque en caso contrario editare mi pregunta detallando esa parte

Comment: puedes agregar las 2 opciones en tu respuesta, ya que el decida como le sirve más. De igual manera si no va a realizar validaciones de formulario, ejecutar algún método en el submit. etc. no le veo la necesidad de crear el elemento form.

Comment: @jorgeGomez listo!